# android:how to use text to speech on non activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

i want to use text to speech in my application, i find many example for using text to speech like this [Android Text-To-Speech Application](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html) . i want to use text to speech from non activity class , for example i have class that genrate layout and return this layout to my main activity , ihave button on this layout and i want to when clicked on this button call text to speech. how can i use text to speech on non activity class ?

Comment: Please post some code and explain where you are having problems. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Create your Speech class as below:

```
package zillion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;


public class Speech {
    private static TextToSpeech tts;
    private static CharSequence SC_str;
    private static String S_str;

    public static void Talk(Context context, String str) {
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        S_str = str;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(Zillion.getContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    tts.setPitch(1.3f);
                    tts.setSpeechRate(1f);
                 //   tts.speak(SC_str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
                    tts.speak(S_str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you noticed `Zillion.getContext()` had been used as replacement of `getApplicationContext()`, to get the context, you need to create a class extends application, like below:

```
package zillion;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class Zillion extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

and define the app in the manifest related to this class as:

```
<application
        android:name=".Zillion"
</application>
```

Comment: Zillion thanks ! works great, i did not notice earlier, commented out line is for newer API versions with Char sequence. Seems older APIs take String instead of Char sequence so S_str should be replaced with str in tts.speak(S_str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a facade to achieve this.

Define an interface for example `TTSListener.java`:

```
public interface TTSListener{
public void speak(String text);
public void pause(long duration);
}
```

In your Main activity, implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TTSListener{

@Override
public void speak(String text){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
      tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
  );
 }

@Override
public void pause(long duration){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
        tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
  );

}
```

Then finally in your non-activity's class, you can invoke the TTS methods:

```
public class SomeClass{
    TTSListener ttsListener;


    public SomeClass(Context context){  
    ttsListener = (TTSListener)context;
    }

   ttsListener.speak("Hello"); 
   ttsListener.pause(4000);   //pause for 4 seconds

}
```

Comment: Hi , it`s return me this error : java.lang.ClassCastException for this line : ttsListener = (TTSListener)context;

Comment: You must pass in the activity's context when initializing SomeClass. Thus, in the activity class (implementing the interface) you should create the instance like this : SomeClass foo = new SomeClass(this);

Comment: @mahdi let me know if you need further assistance